# How setTimeout() works in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, v8

I watched a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MXRNXXgP_0) about javascript in web browswer.
They told about WebAPI when explaining how setTimeout() works.

In the case of node.js, I think node.js have no WebAPI.

How does setTimeout() works in NodeJS?

Comment: It might not be called WebAPI in their particular implementation but it is there, see their [Timers documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html)

Answer (score 1):

You call setTimeout with a function and delay.  The code continues to run, and node eventually calls your function asynchronously.

This snippet shows the flow.

```js
console.log('setTimeout will be called')
setTimeout( ()=>{console.log('hello')}, 1000 )
console.log('setTimeout was called')
```

**`setTimeout` sets `this` to the global object.**

If you use the `function syntax`, your `this` pointer will not be same as the `this` when calling, so you need to stash the context in a closure if you need it.

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){// that !== this;}, 1000);
```